# Applying same macro to a variety of ranges

Tags: excel, vba, macros, range

I have a code that does what I want it to do, but it's HUGE, as i used the macro recorder to make it. Basically, it selects a range, applies two conditional formats and goes to the next range. I can't select the whole ranges at once because the conditional format applies an `AVERAGE` on each range.

Here's a piece of the code:

```
 Sub DesvPad()

    Range("C3:N3").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlAboveStdDev
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NumStdDev = 1
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlBelowStdDev
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).NumStdDev = 1
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
MsgBox "O macro foi executado até Range(C325:N325)"

End Sub
```

I know it's shameful, so I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. All you have said is your have a huge piece of code that does what you want and that this is a piece of it. What issue are you trying to correct or improve?

Comment: Could you use the code in every sheet of the workbook, or may be the just the sheets you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what your question is but I'll guess you're asking how to make your code more "modular" "

```
Sub Tester()
     ApplyCF  Range("A1:A10")
     ApplyCF  Range("A11:A20")
     'etc
End Sub


Sub ApplyCF(rng As Range)

    'here use rng instead of "Selection"
    rng.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage '<< for example

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I tried adapting your code but can't seem to post it here.

Comment: `Sub Tester()
     ApplyCF Range("C3:N3")
    
End Sub`

`Sub ApplyCF(rng As Range)

    rng.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    rng.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    rng.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    rng.FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlAboveStdDev
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        Color = 5296274
        TintAndShade = 0

End Sub`

Comment: I'm getting an error when it tries to apply the color! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help:

```
Sub formatInMySelectedSheets() 'use this just for few sheet
                               'that you want to change
    Dim i As Worksheet
    Dim Nm(1 To 3) As String
    Dim s
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    'Imagine the book has 10 sheets, "Sheet1" to "Sheet10"
    'but you only want to go to Sheet1, Sheet4 and Sheet7

    Nm(1) = "Sheet1" 'this are the sheets you want to change
    Nm(2) = "Sheet4"
    Nm(3) = "Sheet7"

    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'the workbook with the sheets...

        For s = LBound(Nm) To UBound(Nm) 'from the lowest value of the array to
                                         'to the highest
            Set sht = Sheets(Nm(s))
            'here the code shows the sheet to avoid some errors
            'if the sheet is hidden, Show it to  me!
            If sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Or sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
                sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
            'go to the sheet
            sht.Activate
            DesvPad 'Calls you code
        Next s
    Next i
End Sub

Sub formatInEverySheet() 'Use this to do it in every sheet
                         'no matter what!
    Dim i As Worksheet
    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        i.Activate
        ' here the code shows the sheet to avoid some errors
        If i.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Or i.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
            i.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
        DesvPad 'Calls you code
    Next i
End Sub
```